# Best practice to store users "plan" and control their permission in AWS Cognito

Tags: amazon-web-services, authentication, amazon-cognito

Assume I have a web app application and I use aws cognito users-pool to manage my users. Also assume some of the users are just "Guests", some are in a "Regular" paid plan and some are under "Premium" paid plan.

Where is the best place to store the users plan information? Is it better to store it as a Cognito user attribute or in some key:value DB (e.g Dynamodb)?

How should I control what a user can do according to his plan? Should i check the user ID against his "plan type" value in Cognito user pool/DB for each http request he makes to the server? Is there a cheaper (resource wise) way to accomplish this?

Thanks

Comment: Is your application multitenant? Do you plan to use the same userpool to sso to other applications?

Answer (score 0):

If your application is single tenant and you are using the particular Userpool only for this application, you can store the 'plan' in an custom attribute.

This would be difficult to manage if you use the same user pool for multiple applications or having multi-tenancy with different 'plans' for a single user.

To store the plan you can use either Dynamodb or Cognito Sync Storage.